# GIF in XeLaTeX PDF using animate

Tags: xetex, pdftex, overleaf, gif

I have a PDF using the XeLaTeX compiler and would like to add a GIF. However, after reading multiple posts, I've created a sequence of images instead, which I'm adding into my document using animate. However when I press play on the controls, I do not get an animation (stagnation).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
    \animategraphics[controls,autoplay,width=0.4\linewidth]{12}{fakegif-}{0}{2}
    \caption{Example animate}
\label{figure:gif images}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you test this in Adobe Reader? I do not think it will work in the Overleaf PDF viewer (since you used the "Overleaf" tag).

Comment: KDE Okular is another viewer option, esp. on the Linux platform.

Comment: Hi there, Tom from Overleaf Support Team here. As @Dr.ManuelKuehner mentioned, our internal PDF viewer does not support the animations. You have to try it in some local PDF viewer. Adobe Reader is the safest choice.

Comment: Yes, I did test it with an Adobe Reader and the animation is stagnant as well.